# Filtring query in :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  has_many :links, through: :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :links
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

For given user I want to find all his links which have favorite field equals true. I'm learning rails from 'rails guides' and I searched there for simple query to this, but I didn't find anything. Finally I resolved problem using select iterator:

```
@links = current_user.links.select{ |l| l.favorite }
```

But I'm not sure it is a good solution. How do that in rails way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works fine but the SQL query generated by that code will be something like

```
SELECT * FROM links where links.user_id = ?
```

Then the links you're interested in will be filtered by the select method.
If your user has many links and few of them are favorites, it could be more efficient to select the favorites this way:

```
@links = current_user.links.where(favorite: true)
```

This will generate this kind of query:

```
SELECT * FROM links where links.user_id = ? AND links.favorite = 't'
```

you can either create a scope in your links model to filter favorite links.

```
class Links < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :favorites, -> { where(favorite: true) }
end
```

corresponding query:

```
@links = current_user.links.favorites
```

This can be more efficient because that will create less ActiveModel objets.

Answer (score 4):

To add to `@Pierre Michard`'s answer, you may also wish to look at [ActiveRecord Association Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions), which will basically replace the `scope` in the `Link` model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :categories
   has_many :links, through: :categories do
      def favorites
         where favorite: true
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@links = current_user.links.favorites
```

Answer (score -1):

Many to many relationship needs to be,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  has_many :links, through: :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :link
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  has_many :users, through: :categories
end
```

And then you can fetch link records whose favorite column is true as,

```
@links = current_user.categories.include(:links).where('links.favorite = ?', true)
```